# Dealing with quotes inside an Angular instruction

Tags: angularjs

I have this code that changes the text of the button:

`<button type="button" class="btn btn-default" ng-click="saveActiveFile()" ng-disabled="activeFile.saving">{{ activeFile.saving ? "Saving" : "Save" }}</button>`

Instead of it changing to `Saving` I want it to be a FA icon:

`<i class="fa fa-spinner fa-spin fa-fw"></i>`

But because the code has quotes in it I'm not sure how to make it work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are saying you want the text to be an icon instead? Assuming you can have html inside the button tags, you can use `ng-if` to add/remove DOM based on some condition.

```
<button type="button" class="btn btn-default" ng-click="saveActiveFile()" ng-disabled="activeFile.saving">
    <span ng-if="!activeFile.saving">Save</span>
    <i ng-if="activeFile.saving" class="fa fa-spinner fa-spin fa-fw"></i>
</button>
```

Comment: Worked perfectly :-)